# OSM in mapkit vs route-me OSM

Tags: ios, mapkit, openstreetmap, route-me, mapbox

I'm trying to figure out MapKit for the first time.

Are there any difference in the maps provided by iOS 6 MapKit compared to using OSM in route-me/mapbox?

The maps provided by MapKit are provided by Apple's tile server?

Would it be possible to use route-me with Apple's tile server? Would that make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Those are essentially 2 different frameworks. MapKit is pretty straightforward and allow you to quickly implement a mapview with pins, callouts and other layers you might need to display. One setback is that you won't be able to use offline maps or to have custom styled maps.

Route-me (usually paired with mapbox) allow you much more flexibility when it comes to the maps (based on OSM, you can ini theory customize them to look like apple ones). You can even download a set of tiles to display offline to the user. It's a little more work to implement a map using this framework though.